# Remove unique multiple words from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting multiple strings from ajax response so there I am getting a strange string which is repeating many times .I try removing it but it didn't work Can Anyone help me out with this problem
Here is the string which I am getting in the output

```
user =  "[\u0026quot;aniket\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;shivam\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;alambagh churah\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;Jyoti tiwari chatur\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;A-12121\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;prateek@gmail.com\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;ANC-22\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;Ahdada-2\u0026quot;, nil, \u0026quot;mobile appli\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;hari tiwari\u0026quot;, \u0026quot;121221\u0026quot;]"
```

I need to remove `\u0026quot;` from my string ..
When I do `puts "#{user.classs}"` It says `String`

I tried using `gsub` but it didn't work for me or maybe I am not using it properly

```
user.gsub!('\u0026quot;', '')
```

I am sending response from my ajax call
 function download_csv(user_Data){
//alert(user_Data)    //in this basically i am getting the data and from //here I am sending to my controller

```
$.ajax({
  url: "users/download",
  type: "POST",
  data: {user_Data: duser_Datata},
  dataType: "text",

  complete: function(){
  },
  success: function(data,xhr){

  },
  error: function(){
    alert('ajax error')
  } 
})

}
```

Comment: provide your `method code`, which return this user `array`

Comment: I am getting response from ajax call .okay I am updating my code

Comment: change the `dataType: "text"` to `          dataType: "json" and try again
`

Comment: and show me the `code` for `users/download`

Comment: Show the error you're getting from gsub. Although I think you should try CGI.unescape

Comment: How cgi.unescape works ????

Comment: @ hgsongra I have already change my datatype to text to json but it doesn't work.Also the error comes before the ajax call only I have already updated my users/download code .I am just doing puts "sss#{user.to_json}" over there

Comment: You need to do code in `users/download` like this `render json: User.pluck(:name)
    return` to get the list of users array on ajax call.

Comment: `puts "sss#{user.to_json}" ` return nothing for `ajax` call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `user.gsub!("\u0026quot;", '')`

'escape sequence' does not work in single quote string.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you need to use this rgx with `gsub` will help, if you need to modify the original string use `gsub!`.

```
s = "[&quot;aniket&quot;, &quot;shivam&quot;, &quot;alambagh churah&quot;, &quot;Jyoti tiwari chatur&quot;, &quot;A-12121&quot;, &quot;prateek@gmail.com&quot;, &quot;ANC-22&quot;, &quot;Ahdada-2&quot;, nil, &quot;mobile appli&quot;, &quot;hari tiwari&quot;, &quot;121221&quot;]"

s.gsub(/\\u0026quot;/, "")

# => "[&quot;aniket&quot;, &quot;shivam&quot;, &quot;alambagh churah&quot;, &quot;Jyoti tiwari chatur&quot;, &quot;A-12121&quot;, &quot;prateek@gmail.com&quot;, &quot;ANC-22&quot;, &quot;Ahdada-2&quot;, nil, &quot;mobile appli&quot;, &quot;hari tiwari&quot;, &quot;121221&quot;]"
```